# Receptors and their distribution over the human population

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, molecular-genetics

For humans it has been reported that there are three [vasopressin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasopressin) receptors (AVPR1a) and four dopamine receptors ([DRD2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/1813)). (Source: UNIPROT)

Question: Does every human contain all three variants of AVPR1a? Or is it the case that some individuals contain fewer than the three variants found in the total population?

Comment: do you mean variation in one gene or presence and absence of multiple paralogs/copies of these genes? I don't see where you are getting this info in uniprot, directly linking/screenshotting would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: my database search yielded different results: Three receptors were identified with different names: AVPR1A, AVPR1B, AVPR2.

I have actually never heard of a distinct human population completely lacking one gene (I might be mistaken). Usually, only single nucleotide polymorphisms vary between populations. I also do not think that this matters, unless your project addresses specifically that question.

I find [three paralogues](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=(AVPR+human)+AND+%22Homo+sapiens%22%5Bporgn%3A__txid9606%5D) of the vasopressin receptor (homologous copies of a "similar" receptor found on different chromosomes): AVPR1A, AVPR1B, AVPR2 (might have missed one though)

If these receptors pop up in a search in a human database, their mRNA (cDNA) was sequenced at some point from human tissue and annotated to the genome.

[Protein Atlas](https://www.proteinatlas.org/ENSG00000166148-AVPR1A#gene_information) shows two splice variants ("number of transcripts") of AVPR1A.

[NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/552) shows one splice variant of AVPR1a from three different databases (MANE, NCBI, Ensembl). (please see this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iPSq0VfU19c) to use the NCBI-genome viewer)